# How to show the variance identity of difference of a random vector and the expected value in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $Z$ be a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E} \left\| Z - \mathbb{E} Z \right\|^2_2 =
\mathbb{E} \left\| Z \right\|^2_2 -
\left\| \mathbb{E} Z \right\|^2_2
\end{equation}

I have tried to use the identity

\begin{equation}
\langle u - v, u - v \rangle = \| u \|^2 + \| v\|^2 - 2 \langle u, v \rangle
\end{equation}

Let $u = Z$ and $v = \mathbb{E} Z$.

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E} \| Z \|^2_2 + \mathbb{E} \| \mathbb{E} Z \|^2_2 - 2 \mathbb{E}  \langle Z, \mathbb{E} Z \rangle
\end{equation}

Where to go from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{E} \left( \Vert z - \mathbb{E}z \Vert_{2}^2  \right) = \mathbb{E} \left( z^Tz - 2 \mathbb{E}z^T z + (\mathbb{E}z)^T \mathbb{E}z \right) = \mathbb{E} \underbrace{(z^Tz)}_{\Vert z \Vert_{2}^2} - 2 (\mathbb{E}z)^T \mathbb{E}z + \underbrace{(\mathbb{E}z)^T \mathbb{E}z}_{\Vert \mathbb{E}z \Vert_{2}^2} = \mathbb{E} \Vert z \Vert_{2}^2 - \Vert \mathbb{E}z \Vert_{2}^2$

Comment: Why can I do $\mathbb{E}((\mathbb{E} Z)^T Z) = (\mathbb{E} Z)^T \mathbb{E} Z$?.

Comment: expectation is linear operator, so in general $\mathbb{E}(A \cdot \vec x) = A \cdot \mathbb{E} \vec x$, where A is nonrandom matrix. Here $\mathbb{E}z$ is nonrandom vector, thus A = $\mathbb{E z}$